# How to add script editor to NewForm.aspx in Mobile View SharePoint2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, development, mobile-view

How to add a script editor or content editor to NewForm.aspx on my list in `Mobile View` version. I have added one but in desktop view it works good but when i switch to mobile version it does not run the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it's NOT possible. Because mobile view renders from OOTB `Application page(System page)` like `_layouts/15/settings.aspx & viewlsts.aspx` this is common for entire farm so we cant/should not edit it directly.

When we enable mobile view based on site or sub-site context SharePoint will pass the GUID of the list and other predefined parameters.

```
_layouts/15/mobile/editforma.aspx?List=befce8cd-e05b-4482-ad1f-4e3e82f5e5e1&ID=2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize Mobile Views, check the MSDN documentation below.

[How to: Customize Mobile List View and Form Pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb861936(v=office.14).aspx)

SharePoint 2013 mobile rending template locates in:

**C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES**